# How to type forwardRef in separate select component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components, react-forwardref

The technologies I'm using are react, typescript, and styled-components.
I'm trying to create the select component in order to make use of it in React Hook Form.
At first, it looks like everything is correct, but I'm getting an error from typescript saying:

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<SelectHTMLAttributes, HTMLSelectElement>, "form" | ... 262 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & ISelectProps, "form" | ... 264 more ... | "options"> & Partial<...>, "form" | ... 264 more ... | "options"> & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
> Type 'ForwardedRef' is not assignable to type 'RefObject | (RefObject & ((instance: HTMLSelectElement | null) => void)) | (((instance: HTMLSelectElement | null) => void) & RefObject<...>) | (((instance: HTMLSelectElement | null) => void) & ((instance: HTMLSelectElement | null) => void)) | null | undefined'.
> Type 'MutableRefObject' is not assignable to type 'RefObject | (RefObject & ((instance: HTMLSelectElement | null) => void)) | (((instance: HTMLSelectElement | null) => void) & RefObject<...>) | (((instance: HTMLSelectElement | null) => void) & ((instance: HTMLSelectElement | null) => void)) | null | undefined'.
> Type 'MutableRefObject' is not assignable to type '((instance: HTMLSelectElement | null) => void) & RefObject'.
> Type 'MutableRefObject' is not assignable to type '(instance: HTMLSelectElement | null) => void'.
> Type 'MutableRefObject' provides no match for the signature '(instance: HTMLSelectElement | null): void'.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import arrow from "../assets/svg/select_arrow.svg";

interface ISelectProps {
  options?: { name: string; value: string | number }[];
  name: string;
  ref?:
    | ((instance: HTMLSelectElement | null) => void)
    | React.RefObject<HTMLSelectElement>
    | null
    | undefined;
}

const SelectContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
`;

const StyledSelect = styled.select<ISelectProps>`
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.transparentButton};
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: ${({ theme }) => theme.borderRadius};
  font-size: 14px;
  -moz-appearance: none; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Safari and Chrome */
  appearance: none;
  &:focus,
  &:active {
    outline: none;
  }
`;

const StyledArrow = styled.img`
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  padding: inherit;
`;

const Select = forwardRef(({ options, name }: ISelectProps, ref) => {
  return (
    <>
      <SelectContainer>
        <StyledSelect name={name} ref={ref}>
          {options?.map((op) => (
            <option value={op.value}>{op.name}</option>
          ))}
        </StyledSelect>
        <StyledArrow src={arrow} />
      </SelectContainer>
    </>
  );
});

export default Select;
```

codesandbox.io/s/eager-hertz-opbsi?file=/src/select.tsx

What Am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for all the helpful answers!

Comment: Can you reproduce in codesandbox? Read why here: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-hertz-opbsi?file=/src/select.tsx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `ref` is not a part of props in this case.
You should provide two generic parameters for `forwardRef` to help TS narrow the types.

What is `ref`? It is just HTML element

```js
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

interface ISelectProps {
  options?: { name: string; value: string | number }[];
  name: string;

}

const SelectContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
`;

const StyledSelect = styled.select<ISelectProps>`
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.transparentButton};
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: ${({ theme }) => theme.borderRadius};
  font-size: 14px;
  -moz-appearance: none; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Safari and Chrome */
  appearance: none;
  &:focus,
  &:active {
    outline: none;
  }
`;

const StyledArrow = styled.img`
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  padding: inherit;
`;

const Select = forwardRef<HTMLSelectElement, ISelectProps>(({ options, name }, ref) => {
  return (
    <>
      <SelectContainer>
        <StyledSelect name={name} ref={ref}>
          {options?.map((op) => (
            <option value={op.value}>{op.name}</option>
          ))}
        </StyledSelect>
      </SelectContainer>
    </>
  );
});

export default Select;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBm0A7ilACbL5wC%20BUEIcARFKhkwNwBQokscAZxgBPADZIydBsyFiJAWjQNIAOyQqYAzlx4akUfOiRwAkgGUk4jAAV6YAbi5w4EMDGAQVAgPwAuXHAqKCBI-kJQwCoA5hxwAG4oogCuoYIwEdFwAD6BSSAARvo0ANoAutzOQSFh6ZExOtQ6Sl7wFlYwAMKeMCiRRQC8aXJkAHRkwHEABk5w4wJgoijC-vjiAB4VcInAUSrywDBIIAL%20aOqHUJtEwGQwABb%20AIwADM8ApJuQAgceKv6si3ccSQ3Em3C4zSEcDMInEZDaSAwcEGsjhIwElkRMAAPOZMTY7AIAHzTZzXW4POAvd6bO5IHZ3GD%20ADMzzAGxmYBQZHG0X8zypbI5zny6AA1lF6EkVGR-AASHAACjw9yOxmoAEpkUS4KqQiMlKJoAIRukUF4uawNAAhJIwGCeaibQ3QfxEO4HEEzfLQMj6J7swQQUQ3ODuz2bH3kfTyKDc4BJE5wBXK3V0kI0LX9HV6pAjKN%20qAIeOJp0zQgaeTfABeqUeABZ2Zt5CAINX5CgwGBUHGVGd-CpPCC4AB6ABUcAAYsBWIQ1nAxyOZvIiEh8mKDh2uz3zf3AkPYuPoShDBEtjK4B07vQM4uZp3u6Rd6lB2pNgAyXyENCJzAzT-oECxg4DMzgQHaIZqAOB4zI0YJNJ4UIwsMACCUD0EQyJDGioBRKScBfD8nj%20Cg%20QCMGdpes4ERRIyTxCp83K8lE-iRHSEQwKC4KQq0%20LwIMhBQCQ5CUNiAASAAqACyAAyCIYAAouIIQaNgeLtLYrjEoqqauO4iHYFU6rYLOWY6iB1FIDASRQCocCKqBcDYkSjnONi8mdN0vRqFALnOP5-nubCEgeYEwRIP0OBGbQs6RbO1B%20QFSU4Hpvw%20CMICdjprhmfZrlJW5qWePEiQpJFrgjAkyRIAlKVgCM0XYiORUqIlBXOBqGqNO1TkjshcIeW1gV9XxXQaN5%20hDU1iUatwmrgkgax8PAfqGEkoi8e0HBAA)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. This shows much I need to learn about TS yet. I don't fully understand yet how typing in those angle brackets works, but I will try to analyze it. 
From what I see the order matters (<HTMLSelectElement, ISelectProps> vs <ISelectProps, HTMLSelectElement>).

Comment: @zagoor The order matters are not because of some typescript feature, it's due to type definition, check my answer for more info.

Comment: You can read about generics here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Answer (score 0):

You never typed the `ref` object, check examples in [React TypeScript Cheatsheet - `forwardRef`](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/forward_and_create_ref/).

```
// T typing the ref
forwardRef<T, P = {}>(...)

// Full typing signature
function forwardRef<T, P = {}>(render: ForwardRefRenderFunction<T, P>): ForwardRefExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<T>>;

// BAD - ref object untyped
const Select = forwardRef(({ options, name }: ISelectProps, ref) => {...}

// GOOD - ref object typed
const Select = forwardRef<HTMLSelectElement, ISelectProps>(
  ({ options, name }, ref) => {...}
);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-architecture-7gsnp?file=/src/select.tsx:665-1038