# Converting AbstractComponent in TypeScript when using ForwardRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, flowtype

I have many components that use forward refs built in Flow:

```
const ComponentWithRef: AbstractComponent<Props, HTMLInputElement> = forwardRef<
  Props,
  HTMLInputElement,
>(function Component(props: Props, ref): Node {


  const innerRef = useRef(null);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => innerRef.current);

  return <div>MyComponent</div> 
})
```

Im trying to convert this codebase to Typescript but AbstractComponent is not part of Typescript.

How do I handle converting Flow's React.AbstractComponent into something Typescript can support:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to get rid of `AbstractComponent` type. Consider this example:

```js
import React, { forwardRef, useRef, useImperativeHandle, ForwardedRef } from 'react'

type Props = {}


// React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<HTMLInputElement & React.RefAttributes<Props>>
const ComponentWithRef =
  forwardRef<
    Props,
    HTMLInputElement
  >((props: Props, ref) => {
    const innerRef = useRef(null);

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
      greet: () => 'Hello Batman :)'
    }));

    return <div ref={innerRef}>MyComponent</div>
  })
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBm0A7ilACbL7YCuAzkpTfQJLhJQozABuSAEigB2ZADZJsAMWKkySCknxwAvgSgQQcAORRUGTQCh9MAJ5gkcAApqwtOAF5cSw-oD0LxLpgA6KVBLlKAFEADwguNABhdUhBJEEYAB4%20ABUAWQAZZkEwahhAsRA4%20AAyD3RvSgBBGBgoYAAjXKRaBKsIGwA%20Dv00CEFaeCjwPqKAdWAYAAtKe304AmkAhQS5%20ctrWkxV%20ZSMrJy8gqLVjoAKU7ANgC519s24HXwASnsO3G24Xv74YEFYqBmDjoDAUp0E1BEIieAG5DGs4MDWGYOFxeAJhGJTo9sKcXnY3qccB95gBzHRIGA3XGvLR8JCQiBwABCnBAQjgVyeBnhSieMLhax0MGoUEEcASZB4DwUdhwv3%20lCUHVSxiGMSKCRcku43XmvKAA)

TypeScript is able to infer that `ComponentWithRef` is `ForwardRefExoticComponent`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66312566/how-to-type-forwardref-in-separate-select-component/66312711#66312711) you can find other `forwardRef` question